# Странный баг при совмещении GetSaveFileName() и fopen()

Tags: c, fopen

Есть две функции.

Первая функция открывает диалог выбора имени файла для сохранения, после чего сохраняет данные в указанный файл.

Вторая функция реализует автоматическое сохранение в файл `temp`, чтобы при внезапном отказе приложения у пользователя был шанс восстановить свою работу.

Проблема в том, что если использовать первую функцию и сохранить данные в файл `temp`, то функция автоматического сохранения больше не может открыть файл, при этом `errno` содержит значение `2`. При этом, файл `temp` остается доступен для открытия, изменения и удаления извне программы. То есть, он не находится в открытом состоянии. Если использовать первую функцию и сохранить данные в другой файл, то функция автоматического сохранения вновь сможет открывать файл `temp`.

Я долго думал, что проблема связана с тем, что я забыл сделать `fclose()`, но, вроде бы, это не так. Логирование в консоль показывает, что первая функция корректно закрывает файл. Такое ощущение, что после использования функции `GetSaveFileName()` выбранный в этом диалоге файл блокируется, и я не понимаю, что с этим делать.

Вот реальный код:

```
// Сохранение карты в файл.
// В случае успешного сохранения возвращает 1.
// Иначе возвращает 0.
int map_save(void)
{
    char file_name[MAX_PATH];
    file_name[0] = 0;

    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    memset(&ofn, 0, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);

    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.hInstance = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrCustomFilter = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrFile = file_name;
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrTitle = NULL;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;

    if (GetSaveFileName(&ofn) != 0)
    {
        printf("\nДля сохранения карты выбран файл: %s\n", file_name);

        // Открываем.
        FILE *f = fopen(file_name, "wb");
        if (f == NULL)
        {
            printf("map_save(), не удалось открыть файл.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        printf("map_save(), файл успешно открыт.\n");

        // Закрытие файла.
        // Для избавления от дублирования.
        void file_close(void)
        {
            if (fclose(f) != 0)
            {
                printf("map_save(), не удалось закрыть файл.\n");
            } else {
                printf("map_save(), файл успешно закрыт.\n");
            }
        }

        // Записываем.
        if (fwrite(map, sizeof(uint8_t) * MAP_WIDTH * MAP_HEIGHT, 1, f) != 1)
        {
            printf("map_save(), не удалось записать данные в файл.\n");
            file_close();
            return 0;
        }
        printf("map_save(), данные успешно записаны в файл.\n");

        // Закрываем файл.
        file_close();

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Обработка автоматического сохранения.
void auto_save_processing(const float _dt)
{
    static float t = 0.f;
    t += _dt;
    if (t < 3)
    {
        return;
    }
    t = 0;

    printf("\nАвтоматическое сохранение...\n");

    FILE *f = fopen("maps/temp", "wb");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("auto_save_processing(), не удалось открыть файл.\n");
        printf("errno: %i\n", errno);
        return;
    }
    printf("auto_save_processing(), файл успешно открыт.\n");

    // Закрытие файла.
    // Для избавления от дублирования.
    void file_close(void)
    {
        if (fclose(f) != 0)
        {
            printf("auto_save_processing(), не удалось закрыть файл.\n");
        } else {
            printf("auto_save_processing(), файл успешно закрыт.\n");
        }
    }

    // Пытаемся записать в файл.
    if (fwrite(map, sizeof(uint8_t) * MAP_WIDTH * MAP_HEIGHT, 1, f) != 1)
    {
        printf("auto_save_processing(), не удалось записать данные в файл.\n");
        file_close();
        return;
    }
    printf("auto_save_processing(), данные успешно записаны в файл.\n");

    // Закрываем файл.
    file_close();
    return;
}
```

PS. У меня была догадка, и она подтвердилась. После выбора файла в диалоге `GetSaveFileName()` происходит смена каталога, который считается рабочим каталогом приложения. И последующий вызов:

```
fopen("maps/temp", "wb");
```

На самом деле пытается открыть файл `"maps/maps/temp"`. Такой папки не существует, поэтому `fopen()` возвращает `NULL`.

Что же с этим делать?

Answer (score 0):

Ситуация прояснилась.

Суть проблемы заключалась в том, что если для члена `Flags` используемой структуры `OPENFILENAME` не задан флаг `OFN_NOCHANGEDIR`, то `GetSaveFileName()` приводит к смене рабочего каталога.

Comment: По-моему, суть проблемы в том, что вы используете относительный путь в `fopen`, а надо все относительные пути преобразовывать в абсолютные и использовать их. См. [realpath](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html)

Comment: Я просто не знал, что `GetSaveFileName()` может менять относительный путь.

Comment: Дело в том, что много кто ещё может менять рабочий каталог, поэтому вариант с относительными путями крайне плох.